# Mysql превышена длина текста

Tags: mysql

Стоит тип данных longText и не получается внести данные в базу.

```
Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

Comment: Вам предлагается сменить тип поля в базе данных, на **TEXT** или **BLOB**.

Comment: Менял всеравно не помогает.

Comment: После смены текст ошибки тот же? Вы уверены, что изменения были применены?

Comment: Да ошибка та же,изменения применены точно!

Answer (score 1):

Покажите `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

> In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

Какой `ROW_FORMAT` используется сейчас? Судя по тексту ошибки, не `DYNAMIC` или `COMPRESSED`

Как говорит [мануал](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format-antelope.html), для форматов `COMPACT` и `REDUNDANT` в полях типа `BLOB` префикс размером 768 байт размещается прямо в строке и, соответственно, вся строка целиком может выходить за предел 8кб и провоцировать ошибку.

Comment: Сменил тип таблиц на My_Isam и заработало,был InoDB

Comment: O_o Не, если вам данные в таблице всё равно не нужны - то blackhole будет лучше.  myisam и innodb - это `ENGINE`. `ROW_FORMAT` - другая настройка.

Comment: Как это не нужны) нужны конечно

Comment: "Нужны данные" и "нетранзакционное хранилище" - взаимоисключающие параграфы. Хранилище или транзакционное (для mysql из проверенных это только innodb) или вам всё равно, что станет с данными. Но во втором случае лучше взять blackhole, он хотя бы честно говорит, что данные не сохраняет.